# Disabling keyboard shortcuts using javascript not working in Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, cross-browser, keyboard-shortcuts

I have tried to disable `cmd+r` and `cmd+l` shortcuts using javascript, it's working fine in all browsers except safari.

Please check [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abtraju1/u8ga9pos/).

```
var isMacOS = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("mac") != -1;
$("input, textarea").on('keydown',function(ev){
    checkKeyBoardEvents(ev, true);
}).on('keyup',function(ev){
    checkKeyBoardEvents(ev);
}).on('keypress',function(ev){
    checkKeyBoardEvents(ev);
});
function checkKeyBoardEvents(ev, printChar){
    var keyCode = ev.keyCode;
    var charCode = String.fromCharCode(keyCode);
    if((isMacOS && ev.metaKey) || ev.ctrlKey){
        $("#keyLogs").append("<p>You pressed "+ (ev.ctrlKey ? "ctrl":"cmd")+"+"+charCode); 
    }
    if(((isMacOS && ev.metaKey) || (!isMacOS && ev.ctrlKey)) && (keyCode === 76 || keyCode === 82)){
        if(printChar){
        var currentValue = $(ev.target).val();
        $(ev.target).val(currentValue + (currentValue.length ? ". " : "") +"You pressed cmd+"+charCode+". " );
    }
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The high-leveled system event, e.g. CMD+F - means search on the page, bubbling on the document or window.
BUT! You cant override CTRL+R, CTRL+W or CMD events in safari.

Better way to prevent user for refreshing page is
     window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {}

You need to use `capturing` phase of events to handle and prevent it from default behaviour.

For example

```
function preventFn(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === YOU_KEY_CODE && event.metaKey) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
}
document.addEventListener('keydown', preventFn, true); // true means use capture phase of event
```

for example you can use external library to organize you shortcuts, you code would be better and clean.

[hotkeys](https://github.com/jaywcjlove/hotkeys) - Popular

[stack-shortcuts](https://github.com/BusinessDuck/stack-shortcuts) - Small